Potree does not look at the specified target
I have a point cloud that I am publishing in Potree as I have several times.  This time for some reason the camera position loads fine but it does NOT point at the specified target!  What is wrong with this example? (Like I said I have made this work fine a dozen times or more.)
<script>

    window.viewer = new Potree.Viewer(document.getElementById("potree_render_area"));
    
    viewer.setEDLEnabled(true);
    viewer.setFOV(60);
    viewer.setPointBudget(2_000_000);
    <!-- INCLUDE SETTINGS HERE -->
    viewer.loadSettingsFromURL();
    
    viewer.setDescription("");
    
    viewer.loadGUI(() => {
        viewer.setLanguage('en');
        $("#menu_appearance").next().show();
        $("#menu_tools").next().show();
        $("#menu_clipping").next().show();
        viewer.toggleSidebar();
    });
    
    

    Potree.loadPointCloud("./pointclouds/P250035_Weitman/metadata.json", "P250035_Weitman", e => {
        let scene = viewer.scene;
        let pointcloud = e.pointcloud;
        
        let material = pointcloud.material;
        material.size = 1;
        material.pointSizeType = Potree.PointSizeType.ADAPTIVE;
        material.shape = Potree.PointShape.SQUARE;
        material.activeAttributeName = "rgba";
        
        scene.addPointCloud(pointcloud);

        scene.view.position.set(7308480.365, 364389.292, 156.304);
        scene.view.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(7308467.156, 364386.275, 143.757));
        
        viewer.fitToScreen();
    });

    
    
</script>

